# arabic database is not working, laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

Heelo guys , i'm trying to retrieve a stored arabic information from my sql database , the data has arrived successfully , but not arabic , it came like that :
[NON Arabic characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3peW.png)

any one can help ?
 [here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RCMa.png)

Comment: user header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

Comment: Do you have this line in `config/database.php` in your connections array: `'charset'  => 'utf8',`

Comment: yes i have 'charset' => 'utf8',

Comment: Add this: to `config/database.php`  - `'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci'`

Comment: it was utf8_unicode_ci , i tryed editing it like you said but still the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we suppose database tables were set to a Latin-1

**1-Export the data as Latin-1.** Because MySQL knows that the table is already using a Latin-1 encoding, it will do a straight export of the data without trying to convert the data to another character set. If you try to export as UTF-8, MySQL appears to attempt to convert the (supposedly) Latin-1 data to UTF-8 – resulting in double encoded characters (since the data was actually already UTF-8).

**2-Change the character set in the exported data** file from ‘latin1’ to ‘utf8’. Since the dumped data was not converted during the export process, it’s actually UTF-8 encoded data.

**3-Create your new table as UTF-8** If your CREATE TABLE command is in your SQL dump file, change the character set from ‘latin1’ to ‘utf8’.

**4-Import your data normally.** Since you’ve got UTF-8 encoded data in your dump file, the declared character set in the dump file is now UTF-8, and the table you’re importing into is UTF-8, everything will go smoothly.